# Is it Possible to have common showModalBottomSheet for multiple pages in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I want to make Bottom Sheet as a separate function but can't find anywhere how to achieve it. Everywhere Bottom Sheet is added as a function but is it possible to make Bottom Sheet as a common function so that I can reuse that some where else?

Comment: Yes, it is possible? Can you include the snippet that you've tried and encounter issues?

Comment: Thanks for responding @YeasinSheikh, its working now actually the issue was with the JSON data,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use common `showModalBottomSheet` you need to pass current `context` like

```dart
void appModalBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return Text("Common bottomSheet");
    },
  );
}
```

More about [**`showModalBottomSheet`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html)

Comment: what if i need to use this appModalBottomSheet in different page..?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can create the common showModalBottomSheet and add the parameter as child for your view

```
 ///
 /// Show app modal bottomsheet
 ///
 Future<T?> showAppModalBottomSheet<T>({
   required BuildContext context,
   required Widget child,
   bool? isScrollControlled,
   ShapeBorder? shape,
   bool isDismissible = true,
 }) {
   return showModalBottomSheet<T>(
     isDismissible: isDismissible,
     context: context,
     elevation: AppConstants.modalElevation,
     barrierColor: AppColors.barrierColor,
     isScrollControlled: isScrollControlled ?? true,
     enableDrag: true,
     backgroundColor: AppColors.modalColor.ofContext(_context),
     shape: shape ?? AppConstants.modalShapeBorder,
     builder: (BuildContext context) {
       return child;
     },
   );
 }
```